# NPM appears to do nothing on Linux Mint 15

Tags: node.js, npm, linux-mint

searched, and did not see this specific problem.

Trying to get a MEAN stack built on my Linux Mint machine, and bumping into a bit of an unusual issue.

Got MongoDB installed, and finally got it running correctly (none of the instructions ANYWHERE mentioned having to create the /data/db/ directory and set permissions, go figure).... it works now.

Got NodeJS installed, and it appears to work correctly.

I had been told (apparently incorrectly) that NPM installs right alongside Node, with:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

but:

```
$ npm
bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

So I go ahead and install NPM separately.

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

Seems to work, so far, no errors, and it looks like it is pulling down the NPM package and installing it...

```
$ nodejs -v
v0.10.21
$ npm -v
$
```

?? It simply fails to respond without any error... so I try:

```
$ npm install grunt -g --save-dev
$
```

Same completely silent failure... in fact, NOTHING I could do gets a response out of NPM.

Looked all over the web, and saw nothing similar anywhere... found out that NPM holds its cache files in ~/.npm and noticed that this folder didn't exist (kinda like the mongo issue above), so I created it, and set permissions to 7777... still nothing.

Purged and re-installed both node and npm, tried installing them both together and separately (yes, desperation)... still no love.

WTF am I doing wrong?

I would love, eventually, to have a nice development environment setup, hopefully with Cloud9 as a local IDE.... but already pulling my hair out.

=========================================================================================

OK, after a few more headaches, this is up and built now... thank you all.

Would love to mark both as answers, but it won't let me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe npm comes with the nodejs installation in the apt repo. Try to install npm separately using the following tutorial http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1688 'To install NPM ....'

====== Edit ====

node and npm IS separate. Follow the [official wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation) and everything should be fine

Comment: Understood... As stated above, I installed the two seperately using the recommended repo; but it just sits there. The page you listed looks a bit outdated, and for Ubuntu 10,04; not sure that one would be relevant for a Linux Mint 15 configuration.

Comment: If all else fails, install node from source. Follow [the official Wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) for installation from source. Definitely worked for me for Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: Will do, then.  I just despise compiling from source... there are always issues; will report back after doing so.

Comment: Compiling from source, from the official nodejs.org site did *NOT* include npm.  Included screenshot of terminal in post.

Comment: Marked you as the answer since you needed the points more... sorry, Brandon.

Answer (score 2):

npm **does** come with node.  Where is apt-get pulling it from?  I install the Mac OS X packages on my Mac for development and npm does in fact come with it.  I compile from source on my CentOS server and npm comes with it.

Your package provider may be providing them separately as a (in)convenience to you.

As for why your npm command does not work after installation, I can't say for sure, but I am suspicious of your use of --save-dev and -g together.

-g means to install globally, which means 2 things:

1. It will be installed outside of your npm package's structure into a system location like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin
2. It requires root access to install.  Did you use sudo to run it with root access?

Both of those requirements conflict with --save-dev which records the package as a dependency in your package.json file so that future `npm install` commands will install that package **within** the project space.

That said, I happen to know a lot about grunt.  It has 2 parts, a globally installed tool and the package-specific tool.  The correct way to install it is:

```
$ [sudo] npm install -g grunt-cli
$ npm install grunt --save-dev
```

This will install the `grunt-cli` package into a system location guaranteed to be in the $PATH, which turns around and looks for a package-specific grunt installed which is **not** system-wide.

Comment: Umm... apt-get itself doesn't work without using root access, as listed above - "sudo apt-get install npm". I understand you are using Mac, even though this does use basically the same bash, they use different repos; I can assure you, npm was not present after installing node. As for the complaint about the command I tried to run with npm? Immaterial... if it was a bad command, it should have thrown an error, but it did absolute squat... tried numerous commands, 'npm -v', 'npm update', etc... all failed in the exact same way.

Comment: Clearly apt-get requires root.  I said npm requires root if you specify `-g`

Comment: ok... that makes more sense, then... I was told explicitly to not use sudo npm as it creates issues. Either way, I simply get zero response from it. I would really rather avoid compiling the entire thing from source.

Comment: What I am telling you (and leorex agrees below) is that the apt-get package you are installing may not come with npm, but "official" packages certainly do.

Answer (score 0):

When installing nodejs with npm, this one-liner worked for me.

sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm